# How to load image from server into Recyclerview

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In my application I want use nested `recyclerviews`. 
One of these `Recyclerview` for show list of data and another Recyclerview should show list of images. 
**Such as below image:** 
[image: My image is here]

I have strange problem! 
When my images more than one, copy image one and replace with other images!

For show images from server, server send to me base64 and I decode it and then show into adapter.

**My Adapter code for show list :**

```
class TestsListAdapterSimple(val items: List<Result>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TestsListAdapterSimple.ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var context: Context

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemTestHistoryBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        context = parent.context
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(items[position])
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = items.size

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemTestHistoryBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "CheckResult")
        fun bind(item: Result) {
            binding.apply {
                if (item.files != null) {
                    if (item.files.isNotEmpty()) {
                        val imagesAdapter = ImagesAdapterSimple(item.files.toMutableList(), context)
                        //imagesAdapter.setData(item.files)
                        avatarImg.apply {
                            addItemDecoration(OverlapRecyclerViewDecoration(3, -100))
                            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
                            setHasFixedSize(true)
                            adapter = imagesAdapter
                        }
                    }
                }
                //Click
                binding.root.setOnClickListener {
                    onItemClickListener?.let {
                        it(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((Result) -> Unit)? = null

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (Result) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

**My adapter code for show images :**

```
class ImagesAdapterSimple(val items: MutableList<File>, val context: Context) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ImagesAdapterSimple.ViewHolder>() {

    private val userToken by lazy { GoodPrefs.getInstance().getString(USER_TOKEN, "") }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImagesAdapterSimple.ViewHolder {
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        val binding = ItemCircleImagesBinding.inflate(inflater, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImagesAdapterSimple.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind()
        holder.setIsRecyclable(false)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = if (items.size > 2) 3 else 1

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: ItemCircleImagesBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
        fun bind() {
            binding.apply {
                items.forEach { item ->
                    avatarLoading.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    ApiClient.getInstance().apisUseCase().getAvatarImage(userToken, item.id!!)
                        .applyIoScheduler()
                        .subscribe({
                            avatarLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                            if (it.isSuccessful) {
                                if (it.code() == 200) {
                                    if (it.body() != null) {
                                        val decodedBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(it.body()!!.data!!.file, Base64.DEFAULT)
                                        avatarImg.load(decodedBytes)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }, {
                            avatarLoading.visibility = View.GONE
                        })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: i think the problem being with view holder with position item ...... hmm I prefer to work directly in onBindViewHolder using (position: Int) , I mean switch all your code to this area and use it like ( Result item = items[position] ) then start use item object .. im not aware with kotlin but it's same concept ....

Comment: You should set imageView.setImageDrawable (null) In onBindViewHolder() before setting the image.

Comment: It is easy. You just need to use Glide lib in which you can directly load image url which you get from server.